# JQuery Select a radio button (onclick)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function using jquery that updates a form when an image is click.

I need to add to that function so that a specified radio button is selected.

How can I select a radio button using jquery please?

UPDATE:

I'll explain further...I have overlayed an image and hid the radio button...so what the user clicks on an image it will check the selected radio.

Here's how each radio looks like:

```
<label style="display: inline; " for="select_theme_a">
<img src="images/icons/theme1.png" />
<input checked="checked" class="select_control" id="select_theme_a" name="select_theme" type="radio" value="a" onclick="return submitForm();" style="display:none" />
</label>
```

There's 4 radio buttons .. 4 different images to click  on.

Hope this helps

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/977137/how-to-set-radiobutton-in-jquery

Comment: Not a duplicate...that question is about resetting / unselecting

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can I select a radio button using jquery please?

[You can use `attr` method like this:](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
$('#radio-id').attr('checked', true);
```

Comment: I cannot use the id in this way as there are 4 radio buttons...only 1 can be checked but how does it know which one? Know what I mean?

Comment: @Satch: You can apply id to one or you can use `$('#radio-id.eq(index)')` to target by index. You need to replace index with digit for the radio you want to target.

Comment: I just want to target, whichever radio get's selected.

Answer (score 0):

If radio element is inside same parent element as image than you can use this piece of code inside function that handles image click event:

```
$(this).parent().find(":radio").attr('checked', true);
```