# Knockout: Selectable table rows without extending the model?

Tags: knockout.js

I have the following table template that is rendered through knockout:

```
            <table class="gv" data-bind="visible: products().length > 0">
                <thead>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody data-bind="foreach: products">
                    <tr data-bind="click: $root.selectProduct">
                        <td data-bind="text: type"></td>
                        <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Now I want to make the rows clickable and want to assign a css class if a row is selected.
Only 1 (!) row could be selected at a time, so others have to be unchecked.

The simplest way would be to extend my model (product class) with a selected property but this would destroy my 1:1 mapping with the server side.

How should I solve this issue?
How would you handle this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This was my final solution now, no extra hidden radio buttons:

```
<tr data-bind="click: $root.selectProduct, css: { 'active-row': $root.selectedProduct() === $data }">
```

And the selectedProduct implementation within the ViewModel:

```
function AppViewModel() {
    // Private
    var self = this;

    // Public Properties
    self.selectedProduct = ko.observable();
```

Comment: For completeness of answer, I'd love to see selectProduct defined.

Comment: @TelegramSam A bit late but here it is.

Comment: @jtkrause Why is your selectProduct property an observableArray and not an observable only - an object - when you allow only single selection?

Comment: what happens if the user tabs into this row?

Comment: REALLY late to the party here, but how do you bind `self.selectedProduct` to the producted associated to the clicked row?

Comment: I got it, in your click handler (`selectProduct`) you call `selectedProduct(data)`, where `data` is the argument of your click handler that contains the data for the current row. Awesome.

Comment: Right. I have to admit that the AppViewModel snippet isn't as obvious as it should be.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a hidden radio button group to the table, and when the row is selected calling `selectProduct` the radio button is selected.

This ensures that only one row is selected.

Alternatively you could write a [custom binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) using the jQuery `.data()` to specify the selected row.

Comment: The radio button sounds good and it uses standard browser/html techniques to handle the unique selection. Would you also prefer this solution?

Comment: That's how I would tackle it first - but I would be aware that if, in the future, I required multiple selection, I would have to rewrite it.

Comment: This will definitely not happen! Thank you!

Comment: Mh, can you give me a quick example? With "<td><input type="radio" name="activeproduct" /></td>" I´m not able to select any of those radio buttons. And how do I bind the css binding to a checked radio button? jQuery?

Comment: Select the radio button in the `selectProduct` function programatically [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/977137/how-to-reset-radiobuttons-in-jquery-so-that-none-is-checked]. As the radio button will be part of the `activeproduct` group, only one will be selectable.

Answer (score 0):

I created a jsfiddle for myself and you, since the answered one doesn't actually work

The key is a combination of using an observable for the selected item and utilizing knockout's automatic binding of the current item for click events:

```
ViewModel = function() {
  self = this;
  this.selectedItem = ko.observable();
  this.items = ko.observableArray();

}
ViewModel.prototype.selectItem = function(item) {
  self.selectedItem(item);
}
```

and the html:

```
  <ul class="results__container">
    <!-- ko foreach: items -->
    <li class="results__item" data-bind="css: { 'results__item--selected': $root.selectedItem() === $data }, click: $root.selectItem">
      <span data-bind="text: Title"></span>
    </li>
    <!-- /ko -->
  </ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/enorl76/9hLgfzot/