# Durandal: Switch views without reloading model

Tags: durandal

I am using duraldal v2, and on one of the pages I want to switch views without re-activating the model.

To achieve this I leverage approach from v1 using *compose* binding with *view* connected to observable, changed by inline *click* binding in my navigation links:

```
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li data-bind="css: {active:activeView() == 'view1'}"><a href="#" data-bind="click: function(){setView('view1')}">View 1</a></li>
        <li data-bind="css: {active:activeView() == 'view2'}"><a href="#" data-bind="click: function(){setView('view2')}">View 2</a></li>
        . . .
    </ul>
    <div data-bind="compose: {view: activeView, activate: true, area: 'settings', transition: 'entrance', cacheViews: true}"></div>
```

VM:

```
﻿define(['knockout'], function (ko) {
return {
    activeView: ko.observable()
    ,setView: function(view) {
        this.activeView(view);
    }
    ,activate: function (args) {
        var self = this;
        return system.defer(function(dfd) {
            self.setView('view1');
            dfd.resolve(true);
        }).promise();
    }
    . . .
```

I believe this is an awkward way, and in v2 there should be a more elegant way to do this. As far as understand, I cannot use *child router*, like in ko samples, because it reloads model every time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine to me.

Is it the inline functions you dislike?  You could just do:

```
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li data-bind="css: {active:activeView() == 'view1'}"><a href="#" data-bind="click: setView1">View 1</a></li>
        <li data-bind="css: {active:activeView() == 'view2'}"><a href="#" data-bind="click: setView2">View 2</a></li>
        . . .
    </ul>
```

and:

```
return {
    activeView: ko.observable()
    ,setView1: function() { this.activeView('view1') },
    ,setView2: function() { this.activeView('view2') },
...
```

If this functionality is really common for you, you might consider turning it into a widget which could potentially box up a pattern like this.

Comment: I am looking for smth like child router, but without re-activating the model every time. So i could just use markup like that in the [ko samples](https://github.com/BlueSpire/Durandal/blob/Version-2.1.0/platforms/HTML/Samples/app/ko/index.html). As router is just a "sugar over the compose binding", it should be able to switch views while keeping model intact, like I do with *compose*.

Comment: The approach you suggested would not work well in case you have 20 views: as you can't pass parameters to a binding without inline functions, you'd have to create those 20 `setViewNN()` functions in the model.

Comment: You could just create a datastructure (viewmodel) which mimics how the router works.  It would take an array of supported views and expose them as an observable collection with an "active" property or something.

Comment: Your problem is not unlike this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9871477/knockout-selectable-table-rows-without-extending-the-model

Comment: btw, an alternate syntax instead of inline function would be:  data-bind="setView.bind($data, 'view1')"