# IE9, Radio button stays selected after another is selected

Tags: html, internet-explorer, radio-button

I have 3 radio button inputs in three separate divs:

```
<div class="box1">
  <input type="radio" name="paymentOption" checked="checked" value="creditcard_on_file" />
  <!-- related subfields for that chosen option -->
</div>
<div class="box2">
  <input type="radio" name="paymentOption" value="newCard" />
  <!-- related subfields for that chosen option -->
</div>
<div class="box3">
  <input type="radio" name="paymentOption" value="check" />
  <!-- related subfields for that chosen option -->
</div>
```

on page load, the first one is default selected. and in **IE9**, when another is clicked, the first one stays selected! whoa.

what can I do to make it behave properly?

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with the code you have posted, as [this jsfiddle proves](http://jsfiddle.net/mPwpV/) when run in IE9.  You must have something else going on in your page to cause this issue.  Maybe you have event handlers, or some other type of javascript/jquery having an effect?

Comment: I tried your code with IE9 and it works well.

Comment: OK. thanks. i'll take a look at event handlers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a typo in some other html surrounding the given markup. I've learned that IE seems to handle the situations of invalid markup a bit differently that other browsers in that it either duplicates a section, or will hide a section. Since in this case neither of those issues occurred, the markup within incorrect html has misbehaved.

Answer (score 0):

it works fine for me.. but if its a compatibility issue. try using JavaScript to clear out the other items.

try this:
[How to reset radiobuttons in jQuery so that none is checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977137/how-to-reset-radiobuttons-in-jquery-so-that-none-is-checked)

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem on IE 9.0.8112 64-bit ONLY but for different reasons. We had forgotten to assign a name to associate the inputs together. The funny thing is that this worked on every other browser, because we were using AngularJS's ng-checked to set the radio button state (even the non-64 bit version of IE 9).