# jQuery Radio Button will not be de-selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried several ways of deselecting all elements in a radio button field, none of them have worked. I've read so many stackoverflow posts, and so much documentation. I must be so close, but I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong

My goal is to clear the input field (this happens when a user clicks submit on the form). I can get text fields to clear, but the radio button selection just won't go away.

```
#addBudgetElement
    h2#addBudgetElementHeader Add to your budget
    fieldset
        input#inputBudgetElementName(type='text', placeholder="Title")
        br
        input#inputAmount(type='text', placeholder='Amount')
        br
        input(type="radio", name="frequency", value="Once")
        | Once
        input(type="radio", name="frequency", value="Daily")
        | Daily
        input(type="radio", name="frequency", value="Weekly")
        | Weekly
        input(type="radio", name="frequency", value="Monthly")
        | Monthly
        input(type="radio", name="frequency", value="Annually")
        | Anually
        br

        button(id='btnBudgetElementAction', data-action='add') Add To Budget
        button#btnCancelUpdate.hidden Cancel
```

I tried doing:

```
$('#addBudgetElement fieldset input:radio[name="frequency"]').prop('checked', false);
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977137/how-to-reset-radiobuttons-in-jquery-so-that-none-is-checked)

and

```
$('#addBudgetElement fieldset input:radio[name="frequency"]').prop('checked', false).checkboxradio("refresh");
```

and

```
$("#addBudgetElement fieldset input:radio[name='frequency']").each(function(i) {
    this.checked = false;
});
```

and

```
$("#addBudgetElement fieldset input:radio:checked").removeAttr("checked");
```

Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17120576/how-to-uncheck-checked-radio-button

Comment: Can you add formatted HTML? All your tags are missing.

Comment: all I can imagine is your selector not working... when you type this selector in your console, do you get the controls back or nothing ?

Comment: When I put '$('#addBudgetElement fieldset input:radio[name="frequency"]')' in the console, I got back: [<input type=​"radio" name=​"frequency" value>​, <input type=​"radio" name=​"frequency" value>​, <input type=​"radio" name=​"frequency" value>​, <input type=​"radio" name=​"frequency" value>​, <input type=​"radio" name=​"frequency" value>​]. There is no 'checked' or 'unchecked' property ever. Is this the correct behavior?