# How to reset radio buttons in Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have simple group of buttons which I need to reset:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-defaul">
        <input type="radio" name="flip" autocomplete="off" checked="checked"> Front
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default active">
        <input type="radio" name="flip" autocomplete="off" checked="checked"> Back
    </label>
</div>
```

I'm trying it like `jQuery('.btn-group').button('reset')` but it not working.

Comment: you want something like jQuery('.btn-group').attr('checked',false);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/977137/how-to-reset-radiobuttons-in-jquery-so-that-none-is-checked

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[name="flip"]').prop('checked', false);
```

or if you are using an older version of jQuery:

```
$('input[name="flip"]').attr('checked', false);
```

**EDIT**

Check out @Puya Sarmidani comment. That's a great link.